# Ruby on Rails error using SMTP Microsoft Exchange mail account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft Exchange account deployed in a local server. Accessing to this server requires a VPN connection.

My app its deployed into another server and has access to this VPN.

When I try to send an Email I'm getting this error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

These are my stmp_settings:

```
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['EMAIL_DEFAULT_URL'] }
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: 'example.com',
      port: 25,
      domain: ENV['EMAIL_DOMAIN'],
      authentication: :login,
      user_name: ENV['EMAIL_USERNAME'],
      password: ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD'],
      openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the error is in `authentication: :login,`....maybe you can try this approach https://makandracards.com/makandra/27443-interacting-with-a-microsoft-exchange-server-from-ruby

Comment: Ok, let me try that 'hack', thanks @Hackerman

Comment: Can you try to send a email via [telnet](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/352-howto-send-an-email-using-telnet.html) at first from your server? It might be that the Exchange Server do not require any username/password. So if sending an email via telnet works without password your application will work as well. If you got an error via telnet post it here and we have some more infos why it fail.

Comment: That did it, removing username & password and setting `authentication: :plain` did the trick, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send an email via [telnet](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/352-howto-send-an-email-using-telnet.html) at first. Then check which error message you get. Based on that test you can then build the needed configure.

As discussed in the comments already "plaintext authentication" might be the best option but you can find that out via telnet.